# Repluggable connectors of Project ARA

Tags: connector

Looking at various ARA prototype pictures I noticed they all seem to feature pluggable connectors.

Sadly I could not find out which ones.
Can anyone make heads or tails of this picture?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [SMA connectors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector), perhaps the most common 50 ohm coaxial rf connector these days. Two variants exist: SMA and RP-SMA. The former has the center pin on the cable, while the latter has it on the PCB/chassis end:

[image]

The FCC wanted to prevent consumers from using third party antennas on WiFi equipment, so they designed a functionally identical yet incompatible connector (RP-SMA) so that consumers wouldn't have a choice. This of course backfired immediately (China exists), and both types are readily available.

Comment: Yes, some subway system replaced their Edison screw base lighting with left handed threaded bases to prevent pilferage.  I expect they lost a few left handed fittings and the bulb pilferage continued at a lower level.